# Space complexity of adding Java Strings char by char

Tags: java, string, complexity-theory, string-concatenation, space-complexity

When building a Java String char by char through a loop through "addition", it can be observed that the *time complexity* of performing this operation is poor: it is of *quadratic* `O(n^2)` time. However, I am wondering if the space complexity of "adding" a String char-by-char through a loop is also poor.

Here is a minimal example of a program which performs building a String via char-by-char addition with stopwatch timing. The results I got shown below clearly show a quadratic curve:

```
/**Create a String of n 'A's char-by-char.
 * @param n Number of 'A's to be appended
 * @return The finished string
 */
public static String appendString(int n) {
    String str = "";
    // Timed run starts here
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // String concatenation occurs here
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        str += "A";
    t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
    // Timed run ends
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", n, t);
    return str;
}
```

Although I can get the time complexity of the program, I am wondering what is the *space complexity* of building a String char-by-char?

A detailed answer that addresses memory management is preferred. (I suspect it is also quadratic because Strings are immutable, and each time you have to allocate new memory for ever-increasing Strings)

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of [String concatenation complexity in C++ and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400508/string-concatenation-complexity-in-c-and-java) because it does not address *space complexity*. I am specifically asking for a detailed *space complexity* analysis.

Comment: Well, quadratic in the short term.  But old unused strings should be garbage collected, so the memory space needed should only be proportional to the size (length) of strings one needs at any given time.

Comment: So is it really linear space in the average case? Especially for large strings?

Comment: Not linear time, linear space (memory footprint).  And I'm not sure about "average" either, but in the long term, yes I'd think so.

Comment: Is there any better methods than concatenating string-by-string. Is there any space complexity improvements when you use a StringBuilder?

Comment: Obligatory reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Well in the general case it's hard to say.  I've considered writing my own string class on occasion when optimization is needed, but so far I've been able to avoid it.  I think "better methods" depends on the application and the use model.  As a general purpose implementation, String and StringBuilder are well implemented classes.

Comment: So in overall, quadratic complexity (both time and space) implies that adding strings char-by-char is not recommended for longer strings.

Comment: I think that statement may be too broad.  It trips my "premature optimization" sensor.  Implement code in a simple method, applying only obvious optimizations.  Then performance test real running code, and optimize more only where needed.  If building a string character by characters seems correct, using that method is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder where is the canonical question asking what is the best way to add a String char-by-char depending on length?

Comment: I don't think you'll do any better than `StringBuilder`.  It has been designed with this kind of scenario in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses quadratic space. Or, rather, a quadratic amount of space is allocated, because each iteration of the loop will (at least in code which the JIT doesn't do something clever with) allocate a new char array:

```
new char[1]
new char[2]
new char[3]
// Etc.
```

The reason for the quadratic time performance is copying the strings into these ever-larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I posted this question to address space complexity to highlight that adding strings char-by-char isn't recommended in terms of complexity. So is adding strings char-by-char only recommended for small strings?

Comment: Please explain quadratic space. How is more than space for `2n+1` is needed?

Comment: I wouldn't say it would ever be recommended. It might simply be an expedient choice to get something implemented.

Comment: @lexicore it will run `new char[1]`, `new char[2]`, `new char[3]` etc, to create the new string instance. Perhaps the JIT can optimize it to do things more efficiently, but that is the naive approach.

Comment: This isn't right, surely.  Once you get into very large strings, the garbage collector will collect any of the arrays other than the biggest two.  So the space requirement has to be linear, not quadratic.  It will appear to be quadratic at first, of course, when the program starts.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I think this depends upon whether you consider the action of the GC to be part of the semantics of this code. This is why I added the "or, rather...": quadratic space is *allocated*; when (or whether) that is cleaned up is beyond the control of the programmer.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the only reasonable consideration would be the theoretical "ideal" GC which clears things up right after they become no longer needed. Because if you allow GC to be "sub-ideal", there's no point reasoning about space complexity at all. However I've failed to find any good references on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite inefficient, **because** there is an implicit `StringBuilder` being created to add a single character in your loop. This,

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    str += "A";
```

is equivalent to something like

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    str = new StringBuilder(str).append("A").toString();
```

You could greatly improve space (and time) performance by using a single `StringBuilder` instead (and you **can** explicitly size it). Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    sb.append("A");
String str = sb.toString();
```

**Or**, in Java 8+, you could use a generator and limit it to `n` times and collect that. Like,

```
return Stream.generate(() -> "A").limit(n).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: The approach could be even more efficient using `char[] cs = new char[n]; Arrays.fill(cs, 'A'); String str = new String(cs);`.

Comment: To make your question on-topic, can you please state the time complexity as well? I am asking for a detailed space-complexity analysis of how Java manages memory when performing that inefficient code.

Comment: The time complexity is `O(n)` (just like your solution). The constant factors are discarded when discussing time complexity. We could reduce it to `O(log n)` by using longer sequences of `A`.