# Counting Operations of String Concatenation in Java

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand why String Concatenation is `O(n)` time complexity in Java.
We were told that `s1 + s2` is going to both create a new string with length of `s1.length() + s2.length()`, and copy `s1` and `s2` into that new string.
So the following cost was calculated (by them) `2 + 2(n+1) + 1` => `(5 + 2n)`

I'm not sure I understand how my lecturers got that calculated. Would anyone mind explaining the operations of string concatenation to me that justifies the above mentioned cost?

Comment: what would you say `5+2n` in terms of complexity is?

Comment: @Naman I understand that `5 + 2n = O(n)`, I don't understand how they got to `5 + 2n` though. Is the string `s1` and `s2` being looped and assigned character for character to a new string?

Comment: so **if** both the strings are length `n`, you would have `n` characters walkthrough of each string meaning `2n`, about those constant operations, maybe finding their length is what the other person might have termed as `2` and then something similar for the rest of the `3`..showing the code might just be worth it.

Comment: The actual implementation may copy multiple characters at once using low-level operations, but in principle yes, it has to copy each character from both strings.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be careful making assumptions regarding what is happening during String concatenation in Java since it changed internally starting with Java 9.

A good presentation regarding this topic can be found here: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/talks/pdfs/2018%20Voxxed%20in%20Thessaloniki,%20Greece%20-%20%22Enough%20java.lang.String%20to%20Hang%20Ourselves%20...%22%20by%20Heinz%20Kabutz.pdf

Also worth reading: https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9jep-280-string-concatenations-will-never-be-t

And already a bit older but maybe relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15401136/875083