# Time Limit Exception

Tags: java

I don't know why this code is giving me time limit exception for N*log(N) time limit.
Please anyone can tell.I have used only two linear time for loops and one predefined java method for sorting.

```
class Solution{

 public String minimum_Number(String s){

   int arr[] = new int[s.length()];
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(i));
      
   }
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int i=0;
   while(i<arr.length && arr[i]==0){
       i++;
   }
   if(arr[0]==0 && i<arr.length){
       //swap 0 with first non zero element
       arr[0]=arr[i];
       arr[i]=0;
   }
   String ans="";
   for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
       
       ans+=arr[j];
   }
   return ans;
   
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think how fast `Arrays.sort(arr);` is?

Comment: what is the ecpected output and input, can you show here

Answer (score 1):

Please try thi, This is working fine for me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution{

 public String minimum_Number(String s){

   int arr[] = new int[s.length()];
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(i));
      
   }
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int i=0;
   while(i<arr.length && arr[i]==0){
       i++;
   }
   if(arr[0]==0 && i<arr.length){
       //swap 0 with first non zero element
       arr[0]=arr[i];
       arr[i]=0;
   }
   String ans="";
   for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
       
       ans+=arr[j];
   }
   return ans;
   
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
Solution sn = new Solution();
String ans = sn.minimum_Number("532974");
System.out.println(ans);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String operations in Java can be expensive. In general the time complexity of `s1 + s2` is `O(m + n)` where m and n are the string lengths of s1 and s2 respectively. So it is better to use `StringBuilder` in Java. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400508/string-concatenation-complexity-in-c-and-java#:%7E:text=On%20each%20concatenation%20a%20new,would%20be%20O(n)%20.)

So to improve runtime to certain limit you can do (though kindly share the exact constraints of the problem to get more specific solution):

```
public String minimum_Number(String s){

   int arr[] = new int[s.length()];
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
      
   }
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int i=0;
   while(i<arr.length && arr[i]==0){
       i++;
   }
   if(arr[0]==0 && i<arr.length){
       //swap 0 with first non zero element
       arr[0]=arr[i];
       arr[i]=0;
   }
   StringBuilder ans= new StringBuilder();
   for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
       
       ans.append(arr[j]);
   }
   return ans.toString();

}
```