# why running time of this code is 0(n^2)

Tags: java

why running time of this code is O(n^2).(as written in cracking the coding interview book).and how it could be improved

```
public String makeSentence(String[] words) {
    StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer();
    for (String w : words) sentence.append(w);
    return sentence.toString();
}
```

Comment: Copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156122/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-simple-piece-of-code)

Comment: I'd say that's O(*n*) where *n* is the total number of characters in `words`.

Comment: [There are already some really good answers here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156122/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-simple-piece-of-code)  It's a clear duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

For `n` = the number of elements in the `words` array

The `for` loop means at least `O(n)`

Inside the `for` loop, each instance of `sentence.append(w)` should be "constant" since `sentence` is a `StringBuffer`.

Doing constant things `n` times means you get a total of `O(n)`

Comment: Again, StringBuffer, so it's not O(n^2). See the proper answer in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Yeah I answered instinctively, but edited it already.

Answer (score 0):

The key line to look at is `for (String w : words) sentence.append(w);`

In Java, a String append is an O(n) operation.  Because the append is inside the `for` loop, the method as a whole is O(n^2).

Comment: Except StringBuffer, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: You're walking about two different *n* :-)