# Time complexity of string build algorithm

Tags: algorithm

```
String joinWords (String[] words){
   String sentence = "";
   for(String w: words){
     sentence = sentence + w;
   }
  return sentence;
}
```

The book reports this to be `O(xn^2)`

Here is my working:

1 call to create `String sentence` originally

There are N calls (due to N calls for the for loop)

then there are N calls to assign `sentence = sentence + w`

Last call to send `return sentence;`

**Total:**

Which gives O(N^2 + 2) = O(N^2)

**Questions**
(1) Is my working correct?

(2) Where do they get the extra factor of `x` in `O(xn^2)`?

Thanks!

Comment: it will be O(n) only!

Comment: "then there are N calls to assign sentence = sentence + w" true, but why would those N need to be multiplied with another N?

Comment: What abstract machine model/run time environment/programming language? Is `sentence = sentence + w;` constant effort?

Comment: x is average length of word, but time complexity is O((xn)^2). It can be optimized by StringBuilder to O(xn): http://stackoverflow.com/q/7156122/6809386

Answer (score 1):

that is poorly written example because it will reallocate the sentence `N` times instead of once causing the `O(x.N^2)`

```cpp
String sentence = "";
for(String w: words) // this loops N times (if N is number of words)
 sentence = sentence + w; // this reallocates the whole thing
```

If `sentence = sentence + w;` would be `O(1)` then the result will be `O(N)` but that is not the case because:

```cpp
 sentence = sentence + w;
```

is in reality something like this:

```cpp
String temp = new string of size (sentence.size + w.size);
for (i=0;i<sentence.size;i++) temp[i]=sentence[i];
for (i=0;i<w.size;i++) temp[i+sentence.size]=w[i];
sentence=temp; // just pointer assignment O(1)
delete temp;
```

Which is `O(M)` where `M`is the number of letters in resulting sentence which is `x.N` on average (`x` is average number of letters per word).

So the final complexity is `O(x.N^2)` (not taking into account amortization) while it could be just `O(x.N)` if would use preallocation step ...

Answer (score 0):

> **Total:**
>
> Which gives O(N^2 + 2) = O(N^2)

Put your cycle like this:

```
String joinWords (String[] words){
   String sentence = "";
   // words.length is a constant, no calls are made
   for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
     sentence = sentence + w;
   }
  return sentence;
}
```

While `sentence = sentence + w;` is indeed "data manipulation" where does your other `N` in the alleged O(N^2) comes from?