# Stringbuilder inside loop efficiency?

Tags: java

Consider using something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  sb.append('a');
}
```

Is the efficiency of the code `O(N^2)` or `O(N)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the complexity of this simple piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156122/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-simple-piece-of-code)

Comment: You might want to pre-allocate the capacity e.g.: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);`  This is true for most dynamically sized arrays or lists.  Without pre-allocation you're depending on automatic reallocation that could come every log(n) cycles, or every n cycle.  slowing you to `O(n*log(n))` or even `O(n^2)`.

Comment: A long way to write [`StringUtils.repeat('a', n);`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-char-int-) is how I would describe it.

Comment: @ebyrob, no, automatic reallocation can't slow you above O(n).  At most it's going to be O(n + n/2 + n/4 + ...) = O(2n) = O(n).

Comment: @LouisWasserman at worst I was expecting reallocation taking `i` operations every single loop but I admit I'm a bit weak on big O notation.  that would be O(n + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + n) which would be `n * (n+1)/2` operations.  But you're right if doubling the size every realloc that would only be `O(log(n)*log(n))` or `O(n)` not `O(n*log(n))` as I said earlier.  Still I think when relying heavily on array reallocation, it's important to know something about the implementation.  Different platforms use different growth factors.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Comment: -shrug- regardless of the growth factor, as long as it's a constant multiplicative factor the whole thing will still be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It is O(N), meaning it takes the cost of how big you `n` variable is.