# Time-complexity of looking at item in stringbuider - C#

Tags: c#, time-complexity, stringbuilder

I have some long text saved in `StringBuilder` and I want to get some specific item

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//fill builder
int i = someNumber();
char ch = builder[i];
```

what is the time-complexity of the last instruction (`char ch = builder[i]`)? Is it constant

> O(1)

or is it linear?

> O(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a constant as you are giving exact location to get the element.So in this case O(1). More details here
[What is the complexity of this simple piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156122/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-simple-piece-of-code/7156703#7156703)

Answer (score 2):

As per [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f) the `StringBuilder` class stores strings in a char Array.

Accessing this array via the property getter `this[int index]` does a few checks and then returns the array item:

```
    internal char[] m_ChunkChars;                // The characters in this block
    //...more stuff

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("Chars")]
    public char this[int index] {
        // 

        get {
            StringBuilder chunk = this;
            for (; ; )
            {
                int indexInBlock = index - chunk.m_ChunkOffset;
                if (indexInBlock >= 0)
                {
                    if (indexInBlock >= chunk.m_ChunkLength)
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                    return chunk.m_ChunkChars[indexInBlock];
                }
                chunk = chunk.m_ChunkPrevious;
                if (chunk == null)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
        //... more stuff
    }
```

Thus the complexity is O(1) or constant access time.

Answer (score 1):

`char ch = builder[i]`  is  O(1) .

Because StringBuilder used array index.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of `StringBuilder`, it is O(1) because is use `char[]`

```
    //
    //
    //  CLASS VARIABLES
    //
    //
    internal char[] m_ChunkChars;                // The characters in this block
    internal StringBuilder m_ChunkPrevious;      // Link to the block logically before this block
    internal int m_ChunkLength;                  // The index in m_ChunkChars that represent the end of the block
    internal int m_ChunkOffset;                  // The logial offset (sum of all characters in previous blocks)
    internal int m_MaxCapacity = 0;
```